# process.cwd() Different paths in development and production environment

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm using next js 14.

In each page folder I have a file (**meta.md**) that I read using fs. Let it be written accordingly to these files

```
const postsDirectoryPath = process.cwd();
```

In the development environment, everything works and the files are read, this is understandable, since **process.cwd** refers to the root directory of the project. But on the vercel, **process.cwd** refers to *.next*, where naturally the **meta.md** file no longer exists. I have some problems with debugging on Vercel and I can't keep track of everything.

But there is some confusion about how this works in production, since I call my function that reads the files in the top **page.tsx** (homepage) file and it surprisingly works. Doesn't work if the md file reading function is called at levels below (another pages in another folders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use static rendering, you can read and process local files. If you run `next dev`, the dev server has access to these files and you can probably read them. Never tested.

If you use dynamic rendering, the server does not have access to these files.

I think, what you want to do is not the recommended way. Use static rendering and access metadata while generating the pages. If you use dynamic rendering, you should fetch metadata from an external store or API.

**Update after comment discussion below:**

If you use the new App Router (recommended), data fetching is different. You don't use `getStaticProps` anymore. The tutorial you refer to uses Page Router.

You have to ensure that all pages accessing the file system are statically generated. Use [generateStaticParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params) to do this.

Tip: When done, run `next build` and look to the final statistics. You can see which pages are static. See legend:

> ○  (Static)  prerendered as static content
>
> λ  (Dynamic) server-rendered on demand using Node.js

Valuable sources for your use case:

- [Markdown and MDX](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/mdx)
- [Learn Next.js](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app)

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions in the official next js guide https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/data-fetching/blog-data

Comment: Ahh, you use Page Router. `getStaticProps` runs at build time and you can access the file system. All examples use a project root-based folder to hold such files (e.g MD/MDX). This works for sure. I don't think so, but perhaps the special `pages` folder is different. I would place your metadata files outside the `pages` folder. And keep in mind: Data fetching always happens in `getStaticProps` and never in the page component!

Comment: The problem is that I can't use getStaticProps and similar functions in the app folder in version 14. I'm currently trying to generate md files in .next when I run npm run build, but even that doesn't help me since the path is different in production and development environments

Comment: You mix up too many things. You have to step back and invest more time learning the framework. An excellent starting point is the tutorial https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app.

Comment: I updated my answer above. If this helps, please keep in mind cleanup and close this Question as answered!

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I now understand the difference. Now everything works fine